# convert string into place google maps

Tags: javascript, string, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a searchbox and a maps, so when the user write a place into the searchbox the map should be moved to the place that the user has selected.

And i do that with this code:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('addressInput');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input));
var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
   places = searchBox.getPlaces();
   if (places[0].geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(places[0].geometry.viewport);
   } else {
      map.setCenter(places[0].geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
   }
});
```

So when the user change the place in my searchbox everything works fine

The problem is when i arrive to the page that contains the map for the first time because I already have a string like 'Orlando' or 'Chicago, Illinois' (I get this string from another page) and i put that value into the searchbox

```
document.getElementById('addressInput').value='Orlando';
```

but I don't get the place specifics because is not a place_changed event

how can transform that string into a place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work for you is (propably, we dont see the actual code) that you try to do the search before all parts of google maps is finished loading. Place your code in the `idle` event :

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){  
  input.value='Orlando';
  input.focus(); 
});
```

And it works. See fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2L5t3/**

---

**Update**. If you want an automatic search **and** an automatic selection of the first search result / prediction I suggest you use `google.maps.places.PlacesService` on pageload instead. Change the idle function to :

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){  
    var request = {
        query: 'Orlando'
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.textSearch(request, callback);

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            //grab the first item, Orlando, Florida, USA
            var place = results[0];
            input.value = place.formatted_address; 
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        }
    }
});
```

See -> **http://jsfiddle.net/j2Kn3/**

The `searchBox` / `places_changed` works as normal afterwards. This is only called by pageload and return the same lat / lng as if you searched for Orlando and grabbed the first prediction as a user.

I tried in 100 ways, but it seems impossible to select the first item on the `.pac-container` without some user action, tried even to dispatch events - no luck.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I saw your code but in that way you put orlando into the searchbox, but the map stay on sydney and don't change to Orlando right? can i change the center to Orlando?

Comment: @Simo, sorry - I misunderstood that. Thought you just wanted to activate the search.